# SSRS: Accessing Font from Variable

Tags: reporting-services

We're atm creating Reports with the reporting service, but it's not quite defined where to use which Font.
My easiest approach would have been to create a Variable per Report and set the Font in the expression:

```
Variables!FontStyle.Value
```

Sadly it doesn't seem to work. If I print the Variable-Text, I see the Font, but it seems like I need some sort of conversion.

As far as I found I've not seen any possibility to do such things, the only Idea would be with HTML-Tags, but I guess since there is a Font-Expression, there is a easier ways.

BTW: I'm really having a lot of small stuff, which bugs me a bit in SSRS, has someone some good articles / books for "Best practices" etc.?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a font style for the entire report you can set it with a variable. In the report properties there is a sub heading called **Variables**, click the dotted button to add a variable. In the report properties window click **Add** then give it a name you will refer to later like **myFont**, enter **Pristina** into the value as an example. Click okay.

Now to call your variable right click on some text and go to properties. In the text box property window click **Font** and then the **fx** button next to the font name, then enter your font variable you set earlier **=Variables!myFont.Value**.

There you go

Comment: Bah crap, I missed the = at the font, so it seems like it ignored it.
Thanks anyway.